# Using a transparent UIImageView to clip other UIImageViews

Tags: ios, uiimageview, transparency, cliptobounds

I was wondering if there is anyway to use a transparent UIImageView (Box C) to clip certain images that move overtop of it.

In my example I am moving Box A & B which are both UIImageViews towards Box C which is Transparent. Once the boxes collide I would like only Box B to be clipped.

[Example http://www.demonbox.ca/Questions/QuestionExample.jpg](http://www.demonbox.ca/Questions/QuestionExample.jpg)

I know I could simply have Box C none transparent then make sure Box B is underneath and Box A is overtop of it. But for my specific purpose I don't really want to do that. I would like to keep Box C to be transparent as to show my background and anything else that might be there.

As always any help is appreciated.  :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the collision and continually resize the `UIImageView` that should be clipped so that it never extends beyond/overlaps C. You will need to setup the autoresize mask so that the `UIImage` within your `UIImageView` does not scale down as the resize is occurring though.

**Edit**

Here is what I am trying to explain visually...

[image]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CL31.png)